# mysql datetime type and now -month

Tags: mysql

i need get all data from table, where insert date is befor month or after.

```
Table:
id Name Date
1 Test2 2010-09-29 10:11:41
2 test4 2010-10-19 11:11:43
3 test4 2011-10-29 11:17:43
```

Comment: Need a lot more information to help you. What is the name of the table? What is the name of date column? You are looking for rows where the date column is one month before or after NOW? Or one month before or after some other date? Are you looking for plain SQL? Or are you using a data abstraction layer in some programming language?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what yo uare looking for -

This should give all data with date before a particular month -

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE month(Date) < <number_of_month>
```

and this should give you all data of date after a particular month -

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE month(Date) > <number_of_month>
```

Comment: The question was to find records where date is before a month or after. Besides, if month and year have to be compared then I guess the where clause can be modified to also check for the year using the Year('<date>') function of Mysql.